# Batch file to create folder based on filename

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a bat file that will create a folder based on part of the filename.

Below should create 2 folders using the date within the file.
It is 3 `Adobe files` and 1 `.txt` file:

File name should be **20200205**

```py
SP190PED_GRN_SA_960_202002051029                  
SP190PED_GRN_SA_960_202002051029.txt     
SP191PED_RED_PPA_SA_960_202002051029          
SP191PED_RED_PPA_SA_960_202002051029
```

File name should be **20200218**

```py
SP190PED_GRN_SA_960_202002181029   
SP190PED_GRN_SA_960_202002181029.txt  
SP191PED_RED_PPA_SA_960_202002181029  
SP191PED_RED_PPA_SA_960_202002181030
```

This not helping me at all:

```py
@echo off

for %%a in (*806_*) do (
     md "%%~na" 2>nul
     move "%%a" "%%~na"
    )

pause
```

Comment: Well of course that's not going to do it 'cos you want some number of characters in and some number of digits after that.   If you want to stick to native commands then cmd has findstr though I don't know if findstr can just display some characters. Personally I use the grep command from linux which is third party from cygwin. Ideal thing is regex support but windows cmd is very poor for that without something like grep or some third party command.  I have seen vbscript used in the past, for regex  that's powerful, or jscript. It might be possible without regex.

Comment: apparently windows findstr can't even do this(matching and returning just a substring)  `echo abcd| grep -o 'bc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where .:*^|find/v "%~nx0"')do ( 
     call :trick "%%~ni" && 2>>nul md "!_dir:~0,8!"
     move "%%~i" "!_dir:~0,8!" 2>>nul >>nul
    )

:trick
set "_dir=%~1" <nul || endlocal && goto :EOF
set "_trick=%_dir:_=" & set "_dir=%" && exit /b
```

_ Or for alternative name folder layout: `\2020-02-05  \2020-02-18`

```py
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where ".:*.*" ^| find /v "%~nx0"') do ( 
     call :trick "%%~ni" && 2>nul md "!_dir:~0,4!-!_dir:~4,2!-!_dir:~6,2!"
     move "%%~i" "!_dir:~0,4!-!_dir:~4,2!-!_dir:~6,2!" 2>nul >nul
    )

:trick
set "_dir=%~1" <nul || endlocal && goto :EOF
set "_trick=%_dir:_=" & set "_dir=%" && exit /b
```

Assuming:

- That the bat/cmd file will be salve/executed in the same folder where you have the files;
- That all files names in layout has the underline delimiter **`_`**
- That the respective names are the numbers always immediately after the last delimiter
- That the name in the last delimiter always starts with numbers;
- The destination of the folder name has 8 digits length;

---

1. Use the `for /f` loop with the `where` command to list all files in your path/folder
2. Redirect the `where` command output to `find /v` to prevent your bat (`%~nx0`) from being listed
3. Use the `:trick` label/function to set the variable name removing the any strings before the last **`_`**
4. call the function and use the variable that returns to create the desired folder name

```py
set "_trick=%_dir:_=" & set "_dir=%"
```

**[Split string into substrings based on delimiter by Sponge Belly/DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)**

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

  [√] **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**